# nginx with subdomains and two servers

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have two servers: the first one has the IP address 192.168.1.216 and is configured with the hostname `hub.domain.tld (jupyterhub)`. The DNS record is pointing to the public IP address, and all requests on ports `80` and `443` are forwarded to `192.168.1.216`.

The initial Nginx configuration on the first server was simple to set up and is functioning properly.

However, the issue arises with the second server, which is also configured with Nginx as described below.
The problem is, that all requests made to `vscode.domain.tld` are being redirected to `hub.domain.tld` instead of `192.168.1.234:8080` (code-server)

However, when I move and add this configuration to the first server, everything works perfectly.

I want to split the configuration file.
Because I want to containerize Nginx in the docker compose:

- code-server,
- questdb,
- grafana.

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-available/default




# top-level http config for websocket headers
# If Upgrade is defined, Connection = upgrade
# If Upgrade is empty, Connection = close
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

# HTTP server to redirect all 80 traffic to SSL/HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name vscode.domain.tld;

    # Tell all requests to port 80 to be 302 redirected to HTTPS
    return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS server to handle VS Code
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name vscode.domain.tld;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/vscode.domain.tld/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/vscode.domain.tld/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    # Managing literal requests to the VS Code front end
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.234:8080;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # websocket headers
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;

        proxy_buffering off;
    }

    # Managing requests to verify letsencrypt host
    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful to see the config from the external proxy since you've established that the config you've shown us works if run there. Also WHAT (of front proxy, back proxy, vscode service) is returning the redirect?

Comment: On the first server i am using the same configuration file template with:                    
  # Managing literal requests to the JupyterHub front end
                                                                                                                            
             location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;

Comment: telnet connection from the first server to the second one is established.  telnet 192.168.1.234 8080

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is not correctly configured to `proxy_pass`, there is no proxy configuration to direct traffic to the `code-server` at `192.168.1.234:8080`.

In your HTTPS server block lets add this block to proxy requests:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name vscode.domain.tld;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/vscode.domain.tld/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/vscode.domain.tld/privkey.pem;

    # ...

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.234:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding gzip;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes there is a proxy configuration.